# shader is not working

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl

Ok I created a screen sized triangle and it's working perfectly fine.Now I want to add some shaders
to have cool effect. Below is the code and the shader file showing how I did. But the problem is it's not working and the other big problem is any of the method is not throwing any exception.
Means it have compiled , attached and link with no problem... or may be  I am wrong here. 
      I am using openGL 4.2.0 - Build 10.18.10.3496

```
// inside the Game class constructor I called
shader.addFragmentShader(ResourceLoader.getShaderResource("basicFragment.fs.txt"));
shader.addVertexShader(ResourceLoader.getShaderResource("basicVertex.vs.txt"));
shader.getReadyShader();

public static String getShaderResource(String fileName){

shaderSource=new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader shaderReader=null;

try{
File readFile=new File("./Res/Shader/"+fileName);
shaderReader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(readFile));
String line;

try {

while((line=shaderReader.readLine())!=null){
shaderSource.append(line).append("\n");

}
shaderReader.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}

catch(FileNotFoundException exp){
exp.printStackTrace();
System.err.println("couldn't load the shader file");
}

return shaderSource.toString();
}


public class ShaderLoader {

private static int program;
public ShaderLoader(){
program=glCreateProgram();

if(program==0){
System.out.println("Shader creation failed: could not find the valid address.");
}
}

public void addVertexShader(String text){
addProgram(text, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
}

public void addFragmentShader(String text){
addProgram(text, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
}

public void getReadyShader(){
glLinkProgram(program);

if(glGetProgram(program, GL_LINK_STATUS)==0){
System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(program,1024));
}

glValidateProgram(program);

if(glGetProgram(program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS)==0){
System.out.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(program,1024));
}
}


private static void addProgram(String text ,int type){
int shader=glCreateShader(type);

if(shader==0){
System.err.println("Couldn't find the valid shader source");
    }
glShaderSource(shader,text);

glCompileShader(shader);

 if(glGetShader(shader,GL_COMPILE_STATUS)==0){
 System.err.println(glGetShaderInfoLog(shader,1024));
}
glAttachShader(program,shader);
}


public  void bind(){
glUseProgram(program);
}
}

 vertexShader

#version 420 (tried with #version 330 but still no effect)
layout (location=0) in vec3 position;

void main(){
gl_Position= vec4(0.25*position, 1.0);
}

fragment shader
#version 420 (tried with #version 330 but still no effect)
out vec4 fragColor;

void main(){
fragColor = vec4(0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}

Why I am not having any effect? please help..
```

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the shader types:

```
public void addFragmentShader(String text){
    addProgram(text, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
}

private static void addProgram(String text ,int type){
    int shader = glCreateShader(type);
    ...
```

For the fragment shader, the argument to `glShaderSource()` needs to be `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER`, while your code passes `GL_VERTEX_SHADER`.

Answer (score -1):

Oh I got my Mistake, its all the effect of following tutorials late till 5am.

```
public void addVertexShader(String text){
addProgram(text, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
}

public void addFragmentShader(String text){
addProgram(text, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);(here should be GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER as a second argument)
}

sorry for such stupid question and wasting your time.....
```

Comment: You could accept the existing answer instead of adding your own that mostly just repeats it.